# How to execute Ruby code in html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have html content that store in table. In that content I want to pass some ruby code

for example

```
temp = "<html><head>...</head><body>... <%= @something %> ...</body></html>"
```

then after I use temp.html_safe or raw temp

but @something is not printing

How can I do this ?

Please Help me

Comment: '@something is not working' - not working like making your computer overheat and explode or not working like throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

Just doing `@temp = "<p>... #{@something} ...<p>"` in your code and then in your view `<%= @temp.html_safe %>` should be enough.

Comment: "<html><head></head><body>#{@something}</body></html>" - not printing @something

Comment: Can you give an example of the use case?

Comment: @temp="<html><head></head><body>#{@something}</body></html>".then after i try @temp.html_safe but it's printing like "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\#{@form.inspect}\r\n...".

Comment: But where do you build your string? in a view? in a controller? in a helper?

Comment: in layout folder - application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

This sort of functionality could get you in some dangerous waters. What if someone compromises your database, edits the code in that record to do something destructive, and then executes that code through your application?

You should look at using [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) instead of executing ERB directly. (Also take a look at the accompanying [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid).)